# How does the receptacle power actually work?

Tags: psionics, adnd-2e

This is actually several questions, but closely related enough I felt they should be asked as one question.  If the community disagrees, I'm happy to split them up.

The 2nd Edition Complete Psionics Handbook actually has a number of issues where it seems like the writers failed to consider there might be more people in the world besides a single psionicist and their target, to be honest.  But one of the places this is most apparent is the *receptacle* power - it only indicates that the psionicist who creates the receptacle can then draw the stored PSPs from it, but never specifically indicates whether other psionicists (or even psychically active monsters) can draw those PSPs out as well.

Additionally, it indicates that to create a receptacle from an empowered object, you don't *need* to give it powers using *empower*, but doesn't indicate you cannot do so.  So, my questions about this power:

1. Can another psionicist use a receptacle that wasn't created by them?
   1a) If so, does that also extend to monsters with "natural psionic ability" or only true psionicists?
2. Can you use an empowered object that was given powers as a receptacle?
   2a) If so, can the object itself access the additional PSPs stored in it by the receptacle power to pay for its own powers, or are they only accessible by others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some more details in The Will and the Way, a Dragonlance book expanding on the use of psionics.  That book explicitly states that an empowered object's creator can expand the item's PSP pool using receptacle, and that the item can access those PSPs to fuel its powers.  It also mentions that empowered items can activate their powers on their own, such as teleporting the wearer out of danger or using telepathic powers to bend the user's will towards the item's purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer this out of order:

> 2. Can you use an empowered object that was given powers as a
>    receptacle?

The book says "Any vessel can serve as a receptacle for psionic energy if it is empowered first. The psionicist must perform the initial preparation and final sealing described earlier under "empower." **He does not do anything further**; the vessel needs no additional powers."

By RAW the psionicist doesn't add a discipline or any powers to the vessel. The bolded text states they *do not*, not they *need not*.

However, by RAI, I do think if the intention was the vessel couldn't have powers, they would have said it can't have them vs it doesn't need them.

> 2a) If so, can the object itself access the additional PSPs stored in
> it by the receptacle power to pay for its own powers, or are they only
> accessible by others?

From the book: "Only the psionicist who placed the points in the item can use them."

> 1. Can another psionicist use a receptacle that wasn't created by them?

Again, from the book: "Using his receptacle power, he can automatically place 1 PSP into a properly prepared container per round."

The text only states that a properly prepared container be used, not one specifically prepared by the user. Given the authors specified that only the psioniscist who stored the points can use them but didn't mention any such restriction in the storage of points, I would rule anyone with Receptacle can store points regardless of who created the vessel.

> 1a) If so, does that also extend to monsters with "natural psionic
> ability" or only true psionicists?

Putting points into the vessel is done by "using [the] receptacle power" and points can only be used the psionicist who put them in the vessel. I don't think the distinction between true psionicists and monsters with natural psionic abilities matters, so long as either party have the Receptacle power in the first place.

Comment: I actually disagree with the premise that an empowered object _must not_ have powers added to serve as a receptacle;  the power only says you don't _need_ to give it powers, not that you can't, but that's a minor nitpick and the answer is otherwise good.  I think must have read receptacle too many times and started skimming the paragraph that ends with the line about only the psionicist who put the points in being able to use them.

Comment: I would agree with that as RAI. I do think if the intention was it couldn't have powers, they would have said the vessel can't have them vs it doesn't need them. The line before that is what makes the other answer RAW for me though. It says the psionicist does not do anything further, not the psionicist doesn't need to do anything further. The intention definitely seems to flop from one sentence to the next. I thought the RAI thing would be implicit, but I'm editing my answer to include it.